# Why does WordStem return different results for "abacus" and "abacuses"?

Tags: text

I just noticed the following:

```
WordStem["abacus"] (* abacu *)
WordStem["abacuses"] (* abacus *)
WordStem["cactus"] (* cactu *)
WordStem["cactuses"] (* cactus *)
```

Is this how word stemming works?  Or is this a bug in *Mathematica*?

Comment: says right under possible issues, `WordStem` sometimes returns garbage.

Comment: there are a lot of M functions that were probably written by interns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think this is a bug, but a property of the algorithm used by *Mathematica*, which the documentation asserts is the "Porter stemming algorithm". You should google the quoted phrase. You will find that word-stemming is a very difficult problem and no word-stemmer is fully satisfactory.

Don't expect magic. It's called *Mathematica* not *Magicmatica*.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough.  I will look up the Porter stemming algorithm.  Thanks.

Comment: fwiw this http://text-processing.com/demo/stem/ produces the same results

Comment: t'was my pet name!